# C# UWP Designer blank - no frame is showing up

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, designer, blend

my C# UWP project works... but the designer sometimes is broken. If I do something I save my project and later... the designer shows nothing.. is all blank. I cannot move something from the toolbox into the designer. If I close VS and load the project into Blend, still not there. What kind of dark magic is this? If I create a new project, move all source code to it - it works - until I restart etc.

Comment: I'm assuming you're in Windows 10, correct? Also, your version of Windows 10 matches your target version you have specified for your app, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designer is unfortunately quite buggy and it is being fully reworked for upcoming releases of Visual Studio.

I would suggest trying to open the project in Blend and checking if the designer works there.

Also - to see the preview, it is sometimes necessary to rebuild the solution so that the designer has the assemblies ready for use.

Important thing to note is that you have to set the x86 target platform to actually see the designer, it does not work properly when the target is set to ARM or x64.

Comment: yeah I use the "x86" target. Rebuild does not work every time. To click on "Disable project Code" and then again "Enable project Code" seems to work for me.

Comment: Happens to me as well sometimes. If you have the option, try the new Visual Studio 2017 RC, which has many designer bugfixes (although it is still "the old designer" at its core, so not the upcoming one)

Comment: yo ok, ik will try VS17 :D Its a private project. I hope with 2017 the bug is fixed, that IntelliSense on the Autocomplete sometimes doesn't direct focus an element in the list.

Comment: Installing VS17 doesnt change the designer problem ;/ damn